# Консольный браузер links. Как 100% очистить кеш посещенных сайтов?

Tags: кэширование, webbrowser

File -> Flush all caches не помогает.

Дело было так. С помощью links -dump обращался к страничке по http, парсил вывод и т. д.
Далее накосячив с настройками Apache эта страничка стала работать по https, косяк убрал, теперь как и раньше работает по http, но links на вбиваемый URL: "http://test.ru/test", подставляет "https://test.ru/test".

Comment: Попробуйте сделать `curl -v http://test.ru/` - что выведет?

Comment: Unknown option -v

Comment: кеш похоже протух, теперь URL: "http://test.ru/test" открывается корректно